# apache wordpress proxy issues

Tags: wordpress, apache, proxy

I have a wordpress site running on apache (Ubuntu 14.04). This server now sits on our parent company network infrastructure which forces all internet traffic through a proxy. My issue is that workpress is trying to call out to the internet but cant because the proxy. I have attempted to set the proxy info in /etc/environment but it doesn't seem to be working. What is the correct way to force all apache calls to go through this authenticated proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your wp-config.php file add the following information:

```
define('WP_PROXY_HOST', '192.168.1.1');
define('WP_PROXY_PORT', '8080');
define('WP_PROXY_USERNAME', 'user');
define('WP_PROXY_PASSWORD', 'password');
define('WP_PROXY_BYPASS_HOSTS', 'localhost, www.example.com');
```

Make sure to replace the dummy content with the content from your internal network team. Once configured, that should allow you to access the internet through that proxy.

Comment: This worked for everything with the exception of a Flickr gallery plugin which happened to be the plugin causing the 1 minute load time on the homepage. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: @cmullis sounds like you need a new Flickr plugin ;) Glad that I could help!